# Targetting all old browsers (not just IE)

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, browser, browser-detection

I've seen some sites just block users and ask them to update their browser. I just want to serve a separate, stripped down stylesheet to all old browsers (well, at least the popular ones like FF, Opera, Webkit, and IE.) If I'm not going to support old versions of IE, I don't want to bother with old versions of the others as well. Even though FF3.6 is leagues better than IE6, it's behind what we have today.

I don't want to block, but I don't want to unnecessarily implement workarounds, hacks, and shims anymore either. If you don't update your browser you can view bland internet. I just want to be able to target >FF12 or >Safari 5.1 etc. I can use jQuery to do it. So anyone have something like this?

NOTE: I do not care to use things like Modernizr. I already use that and the point of this question is to *stop* using that and serve a united stylesheet to all browsers, not just to IE.

Comment: Browser detection can only be done from JavaScript or the web server.

Comment: I understand that. That's why I mentioned I am using jQuery.

Comment: I really wouldn't go about it this way. Different versions are gonna have different issues/different features implemented. We do feature detection so we don't have to deal with that.

Comment: I really don't understand where I'm going wrong with my question. I have stated I don't want to do feature detection. I don't know how to say that any other way. I make websites. I understand browsers have different features across versions. I can take it back to a subset of CSS that will work on all the old browsers that I need. No, it doesn't use features that causes problems so I wouldn't need to do any feature detection anyway. That's the point.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe instead of targeting browsers, you might want to target features supported by browsers. Great tool for this is [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

Comment: But the point is I don't want to make things work. I already use Modernizr on several sites and it works pretty well. The point here is that people serve special CSS files to older IEs and I want to serve these same files to older FF, Safari, Chrome, etc. I'm not wanting to make anything work or degrade gracefully at all. No shims, hacks, etc. Just a completely different stylesheet.